# Cannot publish ASP.NET Web API to Azure App Service (with SwashBuckle)

Tags: c#, azure, .net-6.0, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have an App Service that has been running in Azure for a while. I have just updated it to .NET 6.0 (and installed Swashbuckle.aspnetcore.cli v6.2.3 locally).

I cannot publish to Azure. When I first tried it told me it couldn't find aspnetcore3.0 and the only installed versions it could find were .NET 5.1.4 and .NET 6.0.1.

Following instructions here:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1485

I added a global.json to my project:

```
{
    "sdk":
    {
        "version": "6.0.1",
        "rollForward": "latestPatch"
    }
}
```

Now when I try and publish I get the following error:

```
    Failed to install DotNet CLI tool 'swashbuckle.aspnetcore.cli'.  Error dotnet tool restore

Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You intended to execute a .NET program:
      The application 'tool' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      A compatible installed .NET SDK for global.json version [6.0.1] from [C:\Projects\MyProject\global.json] was not found.
      Install the [6.0.1] .NET SDK or update [C:\Projects\MyProject\global.json] with an installed .NET SDK:
```

How can I publish my app service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else that finds this issue, I finally fixed it by editing the file "dotnet-tools.json" in the ".config" folder in the project root folder, and changing the version of swashbuckle.aspnetcore.api from 5.6.3 to 6.3.0.

I also updated to swashbuckle 6.3.0, and changed global.json to be:

```
{
    "sdk":
    {
        "version": "5.6.3",
        "rollForward": "latestMajor"
    }
}
```

Note the use of latestMajor rather than latestPatch.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple workaround that you can try is -

- It had something to do with the publish profile that was   causing the issue.
- Create a new one, and check whether now it functions properly.

Also, please try referring this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-api-management-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: I followed the instructions in that link. It has been working for over a year, and it stopped working when I upgraded from .NET 5 to .NET 6.

I have tried creating a new publish profile but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `Swashbuckle.Core` library was causing this issue which I installed from NuGet to try something out. When I navigated to Dependencies -> Packages, I saw an error which stated that this package's compatibility is for that of .NET Framework versions: v4.6, v4.7, v4.8 and NOT for the target framework net6.0.

Therefore, uninstalling this NuGet package got me running! BTW, the error occurred (just to set some context), when I attempted to publish my WebApi to Azure App Service.